# Semistable with respect to nef line bundles implies semistable with respect to some ample line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $A$ be a nef line bundle on $X$. Suppose $E$ is a torsion free sheaf on $X$ which is slope semistable with respect to $A$.

Question: Does there exist an ample line bundle $B$ on $X$ such that $E$ is semistable with respect to $B$?

Comment: Every torsion free sheaf is slope semistable with respect to $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Oh sorry. I should have been more specific. Here $A$ is pullback of an ample line bundle  under a birational morphism  $f: X \to Y$.

Comment: The answer is still no. Take for $f$ the blowing up of a (smooth) point, and let $E$ be the exceptional divisor. Then $\mathcal{O}_X(E)\oplus \mathcal{O}_X(-E)$ is slope semi-stable with respect to $f^*A$, but not w.r.t any ample line bundle.

Comment: In what situation it could be true ? For example if $E$ is the form $f^*F/{\text{Torsion}}$ ?